# Check/listen if all document are created and not empty in login page before entering the app using Pouchdb

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, indexeddb, pouchdb

I have to load users information before they enter the app

I would like to be sure that these information stored in documents are created

I thought about a timer loop to check with interval of 5 seconds if document is created.

These documents are created in local indexeddb

```
setInterval(myMethod, 5000);

                    function myMethod() {
                        //this will repeat every 5 seconds

                       // Looping until the document is not undefined ?
                        db.get('user-information').then(function (doc) {
                            console.log(doc);
                        }).catch(function (err) {
                            // oh noes! we got an error
                        });
                    }
```

If the user-information document is not undefined then it is loaded so the user can enter the app
Is there a better way to listen newly created documents ?

Comment: a better way would be to learn about how to write asynchronous code, at least in your case here using promises, and attach a function that runs when the data has been loaded.

Comment: You right i thought about it, using loading controller module